# How to determine IP of client at server via Netty proxy?

Tags: tcp, proxy, header, netty

Regarding a proxy built using Netty. Note: Server C has a custom protocol. (not http)

Given a client 'A', Netty proxy 'B' and server 'C'

Will the server C be able to determine the IP of the Client A on an incoming connection?

Or will the client IP always appear to the Server to be B's IP?

Many thanks.

Comment: I also wondered if there is a way to add a tcp header to the proxy message that travels to the server.

Answer (score 2):

The server will not be able to see the client ipaddress. It will always only see the ipaddress if the proxy. One way to handle this is to encode the "original ipaddress" in the protocol so it can be extracted later at the server. For example in http you could use a header for this kind of thing. Same goes for smtp etc.